# Why doesn't boost::any have a "getter"?

Tags: c++, boost-any

Using `boost::any` is very useful but it's very depressing that it has no getter, and always we have to use `any_cast` for casting it to type we want. But why it has no such thing? In my opinion the one bellow can be useful member. Is there some bad things I can't see?

```
template <class T>
void get(T * handle)
{
    *handle = boost::any_cast<T>(*this);
}
```

**Edit:**

The only bad thing I see, that this getter requires to have assignment operator.

Comment: And the difference is..?

Comment: Why is this superior to `any_cast` in any way ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "depressing"?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but could you perhaps explain why this is such a problem? I don't really see the issue here.

Comment: In my opinion having member getter is very easy to understand, and use.

Comment: @Mihran: even if it doesn't behave like a getter usually does?

Comment: @Tomalak: the biggest difference is that you don't have to specify the template argument; it can be inferred from the function argument type.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Yes it can be inferred, but it can also be quite tricky, in cases like: `int x = boost::any_cast<char>( any );` (i.e. when the type where you want the result is not of the same exact type as the type stored in the `any`. If the value stored in `any` is of type `char` and you try to do `int x; get( any, x );` the cast will fail with an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because it'd behave the exact same as `any_cast`, but it would be less descriptive. `any_cast` indicates that you're performing a cast, a type conversion. You're *trying* to get the value out of the `any` object. So it's clear to the user that the operation can fail if you call it with the wrong type.

A `get` function is less clear about failure conditions. I normally wouldn't expect that a function simply named `get` *is able to* fail. And if it does, I'm not sure of the semantics of it.

If you want a `get` function, perhaps you should use `boost::variant` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The point with `any_cast` is to force people **not** to use template argument deduction, since the failure or not of the cast is very sensitive to the *exact* type used for construction.

This usage is clear:

```
any x(2); // store an int
double f = any_cast<int>(x); // ok, request for an int, then cast to double
```

This one is not:

```
int g;
...
x.get(&g); // Ok. For now.
```

Indeed, imagine now you refactor your code, and you replace

```
int g;
```

by

```
double g;
```

Now, the new code looks like

```
double g;
... // There can be 100s of lines here
x.get(&g); // This line HAS changed semantics and cast will fail
```

This will likely make you lose some half hours to debug.